# Problem Extending A Class in Clojure: ClassFormatError: Duplicate field name&signature

Tags: oop, clojure, gen-class

I'm trying to extend JButton with Clojure, but I ran into a problem when I try to create my own constructors. Whenever I use `:constructors` with `:gen-class` I keep getting a "ClassFormatError: Duplicate field name&signature" message when I try to instantiate my class.

I *think* I'm following the [Clojure docs](http://clojure.org/api#toc271) properly. Am I doing something wrong?

Example:

```
(ns test.gui.button
  (:gen-class
   :extends javax.swing.JButton
   :constructors {[] [String]}
   :init init))

(defn -init []
  [["Click Me"] nil])
```

Comment: I get the same result, no idea why though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JButton` extends `javax.swing.AbstractButton` which already has a protected [`init`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#init%28java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.Icon%29) method. If you rename your Clojure-init function to, e.g., `my-init` the problem is gone:

```
(ns test.gui.button
  (:gen-class
   :extends javax.swing.JButton
   :constructors {[] [String]}
   :init my-init))

(defn -my-init []
  [["Click Me"] nil])
```